# List of tiddlers with clickable tags formated as links

Tags: tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

I want to display a list of tiddlers with a specific tags. Each item/tiddler should be displayed with a list of clickable tags (its tags formatted as hyperlinks). How do I have to modify the following code (which displays the tags as plain text) in order to achieve this?

```
<$list filter="[!tag[hidden]tag[contact]sort[]]">
* <$link to={{!!title}}><$view field="title"/></$link> <$view field="tags"/>
</$list>
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
<$list filter="[!tag[hidden]tag[contact]sort[]]">

* <$link to={{!!title}}><$view field="title"/></$link> -<$list filter="[all[current]tags[]![contact]]"><$link to={{!!title}}> <$view field="title"/></$link></$list>

</$list>
```